# Verificar a relação de dois objetos em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso extrair de um texto puro o total do valor de um acordo. Eu tenho centenas de documentos com alguns valores, e percebi que geralmente o maior valor é também o valor total do acordo, mas em alguns casos, não.

```
def ata_values(text):
    padrao = re.findall(r'\$\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.?\d{1,3})+(?:\,\d{2})?)', text)
    padrao = [p.replace('.', '') for p in padrao]
    padrao = [p.replace(',', '.') for p in padrao]
    padrao = [float(p) for p in padrao]

    return padrao, max(padrao)
```

isso me retorna:

```
([2500.0, 833.33, 833.33, 833.34, 2500.0], 2500.0)
([1000.0, 800.0, 200.0, 1000.0], 1000.0)
([280.0, 14000.0, 21000.0], 21000.0)    21000.0)
([3000.0, 15000.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 750.0, 750.0, 750.0, 1083.33, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1616.67, 140.0], 15000.0)
```

sendo a primeira lista padrao com todos os valores encontrados, e o segundo max(padrao) é o maior valor de cada lista. Neste exemplo as duas primeiras linhas estão corretas, mas as duas ultimas não, nessas o segundo maior é o correto. Percebi que na maioria das listas que tenho esse erro, existe um padrao, a lista contem o valor total mais um valor que corresponde a 2% do valor total.

Como eu poderia verificar antes de pegar os valores maximos, se existe dentro de cada lista um numero X mais um número que corresponde a 0.02*X?

```
for x in padrao:
    for y in padrao:
        if x == y*0.02:
            return x
        else: 
            return max(padrao)
```

Comment: Na terceira linha o resultado esperado seria 14000 e 280 corresponde a 2% desse total. Na quarta linha o resultado esperado seria 7000 e 140 corresponde a 2% desse total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
padrao.sort(reverse=True)
maior = padrao[0]
if maior* 0.02 in padrao:
   maior = padrao[1]
```

Mas como escrevi inicialmente como comentário: Bem arriscada essa abordagem - principalmente se os documentos são de texto livre. Será que não tem uma coisa mais consistente, ainda que seja mais difícil de achar com uma única expressão regular? tipo, aparece a palavra "total" próxima ao numero, ou numa sessão específica do documento, ou sempre próximo do final do documento? Nesse caso você primeiro isolaria um trecho onde deve aparecer o valor total e só depois se preocuparia em pegar o número.